# Difference between pthread_yield and pthread_may_yield?

Tags: multithreading

What is the difference between **pthread_yield** and **p_thread_may** yield .

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_yield()` causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU immediately.

Whereas, `pthread_may_yield()` will yield if the current thread has used up the given quantum.

```
pthread_may_yield ()
{

    /* Whether this thread has used up its allocated time slice?
       Set Variable to True if yes. */

    if (thread has used up given quantum) {
        pthread_yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: By definition, a thread yields when it has used up its quantum. The quantum is defined as the time when a thread is forced to yield.